# Issue erasing an element from a list in c++

Tags: c++, iterator, erase

I have the following code:

```
list<Item> playerItems = player.GetPlayerItems();

        list<Item>::iterator iterator;
        for (iterator = playerItems.begin(); iterator != playerItems.end(); ++iterator)
        {
            if (itemToSell == (*iterator).GetName())
            {
                if ((*iterator).GetCost() < GetShopGold())
                {
                    SetShopItem(*iterator);
                    SetShopGold(GetShopGold() - (*iterator).GetCost());

                    player.SetPlayerGold(player.GetPlayerGold() + (*iterator).GetCost());

                    //The issue is here
                    iterator = player.GetPlayerItems().erase(iterator);
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    cout << "I can't afford that..." << endl;
                }
            }
        }
```

This is the RemovePlayerItem code:

```
void Player::RemovePlayerItem(list<Item>::iterator& iterator)
{
    iterator = _playerItems.erase(iterator);
}
```

When I run the code, I get the following error:

```
_DEBUG_ERROR("list erase iterator outside range");
```

I've googled it and it seems to be related to my iterator, but I'm not sure of the relationship between the error and the iterator.

In contrast, if I make the _playerItems variable a global one and then start/end the iterator using this global variable, the code runs fine if I use the following code `iterator = player._playerItems.erase(iterator);`

**EDIT**

This is GetPlayerItems() function

```
list<Item> Player::GetPlayerItems()
{
    return _playerItems;
}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction with this?

Comment: Provide a [mcve]

Comment: Rather than writing `(*iterator).foo` everywhere, you can write `iterator->foo` instead.

Comment: What does `RemovePlayerItem` have to do with anything?  You never call it in the code you show.

Comment: Does `GetPlayerItems()` return by reference, or by value?

Comment: `iterator` is an iterator into `playerItem`, not into the return value of `player.GetPlayerItems()`. You are trying to erase from one list using an iterator pointing into a different list.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik - that's not a comment, that's an answer.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley It doesn't matter; the code is wrong either way. Even if `GetPlayerItems` returns a list by reference, `playerItems` is a copy of that list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`iterator` is an iterator into `playerItems`. It's not clear what `player.GetPlayerItems()` returns (since you neglected to show its definition or even a declaration), but whatever it is, `playerItems` is a separate, distinct list - a copy of what `GetPlayerItems()` returned.

You are then trying to erase from one list using an iterator pointing into the other. This exhibits undefined behavior - `someList.erase(iter)` expects `iter` to be a valid iterator into `someList`.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, I've updated the code to include the GetPlayerItems function. So what I'm assuming is, I need to be referencing the original list, rather than making a copy. I'll play around with it some more, thanks for the insight

Comment: So `GetPlayerItems()` returns a copy of `_playerItems` (and then `playerItems` is itself a copy of that copy). Even if you manage to erase from that copy correctly, it would have no effect on `_playerItems` member variable.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are trying to erase from one list using an iterator pointing into the other.

Why can not you use the iterator = playerItems.erase(iterator); instead of iterator = player.GetPlayerItems().erase(iterator);  inside the loop.

Why your trying to accessing the same list with get function call(player.GetPlayerItems()) as you have already a reference available to the same list .